# GeoLabels/Tooltips in Geographic Plots from Dataset

Tags: plotting, dataset, labeling, geography

I am looking to plot a list of list of regions, and attach some data to the GeoLabel.

All the data is stored right now in a Dataset that contains entries of the form `<|ID-> ..., Geometry -> ... |>`

The Geometry key holds the polygons, and I want the ID to be on a Tooltip/GeoLabel.

Currently, I can get a map of the values just by extracting the polygons, and then throwing that into `GeoListPlot`, but I cannot do the rest of the problem this way.

Is there a way to pass in a Dataset, and then use different keys for different things (for example, it would also be nice to take a different key and use that color, etc)?

My understanding is that it is possible from [Can GeoLabels be controlled?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71880/can-geolabels-be-controlled), but my data is coming from a different source, and I am 1) not sure how to convert between the two forms and 2) not sure that that is the best way to do this.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: It would be good to see an example of your data.

Comment: @gordonCoale the issue is they my polygons are mostly hundreds of sides. I'll get a minimal example up soon.